# Netsuite Integration with K2 Smartforms

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, integration, netsuite, k2

Have any of us done any project to integrate Netsuite ERp system with K2 Black Pearl or Smartforms. I was looking for some help to setup the connector between two systems either using SSO or Token Based oauth.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont think K2 have an out of the box connector for NetSuite.

To have the SSO setup, you will have to roll your own Security Provider, [Link to Security Provider](http://help.k2.com/onlinehelp/k2blackpearl/DevRef/4.6.11/default.htm#Custom_User_Manager.htm%3FTocPath%3DExtending%2520the%2520K2%2520Platform%7CK2%2520Server%7CCustom%2520User%2520Manager%7C_____0)